# Asp.net core webapi class property IList<List<Object>> only return first level property

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

My asp.net core webapi is returning only the first level of my json data. Below is my expected json

```
{
  "ProtectedResourceMap": [
    [
      "http://localhost:3000/api/",
      [
        "api://123/localhostapi"
      ]
    ],
    [
      "http://localhost:55974/api/",
      [
        "api://234/blocalhostapi.*"
      ]
    ],
    [
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
      [
        "user.read"
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

But i am getting the following in postman when i test my api controller:

```
"protectedResourceMap": [
    [
        "http://localhost:3000/api/"
    ],
    [
        "http://localhost:55974/api/"
    ],
    [
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
    ]
]
```

My class property is defined as:

```
public IList<IList<object>> ProtectedResourceMap { get; set; }
```

And my controller action is:

```
[HttpGet()]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    return Json(await Task.FromResult(_configService.GetUIConfiguration()));
}
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve my expected result?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the type that you're passing in to the inner list at runtime?

Comment: I am reading a configuration section from appsettigns.json into a class.

Comment: 2 things - did you override the GetUIConfiguration method. It seems like its not reading the configuration sub nodes.
Try running it without the TAP pattern Asynch Await so that you can debug it.

Comment: @DaniDev Yes you are right. it is not reading the subnodes.

Comment: the configuration file may not be formatted correctly?
My suggestion is that you refactor your code for easier debugging.
Take the _configService.GetUIConfiguration() method out of AsynchAwait pattern so you can see what is happening.